# MVVM and VS2010 - Is there a way to specify the tabcontrol without adding code in codebehind

Tags: mvvm

I need to place Tabcontrol and need to stick on MVVM pattern. however I am unable to do that without writing code in codebehind. As of now I have one default tab and subsequent tab contents are dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this one i would create a main view model for your tab control and then for the dynamic tabs I would put them in an ObservableCollection, declared in your main view model.

You will need to bind that collection to the ItemSouce for that TabControl.

That way you can add/remove them dynamically from the collection.

Comment: that is correct but I am not finding a way to add the new dynamic tab without mentioning it in codebehind (which is breaking the pattern)

Comment: @user1684424  It depends how you are adding the new tabs.  If you are using a button for this, then you can use bind its click event to an ICommand in your view-model.  This ICommand will then update the ObservableCollection/ItemsSource that kevchadders suggest.

Comment: Good point. I was coming from adding/removing via a button. Didnt make that clear in my original post